# How to set Bluetooth headset microphone as recording device?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

I've got these Bluetooth headphones I have connected with my computer. The deal is, I can either choose them to work as high quality audio output OR a VoIP device in "Bluetooth devices" window.

If I enable the VoIP service, I can choose them as default audio output and use the built-in microphone. But the played sound quality is bad. VoIP bad.

If I enable "listen to music" service, the sounds are great but I can't use the microphone.

Any idea how to mix those two services and listen to HD sound while being able to record?

Also, the headset has remote control buttons which I don't know how to use with a PC.

The system is Windows 7.

Comment: Related to [Sound quality in bluetooth headphones doesn't change to high](http://superuser.com/questions/120113/sound-quality-in-bluetooth-headphones-doesnt-change-to-high)